# "Failed to build and Push Java app Docker image to Gitlab Registry

Tags: java, gitlab, dockerfile, cicd

Greetings,

I need a support on this issue, I got totally mad about this issue, I tried to use the well known code of Pet Clinc and I forked it to my Gitlab repo, the problem I am facing as attached [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4fT1.jpg)

I did made the code below on the CI.yml file as usual,
**
#start of code##########**

stages:

- build
- package
- deploy

maven-build:
stage: build
image: maven:latest #ubuntu:22.04
cache:
paths:
- target
script:
- echo "Compiling the code..."
- echo "Compile complete."
- apt-get update -y
- 'command -v ssh-agent >/dev/null || ( apt-get update -y && apt-get install openssh-client -y )'
- apt-get install software-properties-common -y
- apt-get install curl -y
- apt-get install wget -y
- apt-get install make -y
- apt-get install gcc -y
- apt-get install libc6-dev -y
- add-apt-repository ppa:git-core/ppa -y
- apt-get install libssl-dev -y
- apt install build-essential procps curl file git -y
- apt install bash-completion -y
- apt-get install curl -y
#- /bin/bash -c "$(curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/install.sh)"
- apt-get install openjdk-17-jdk -y
- apt-get install -y ruby openjdk-8-jdk openjdk-11-jdk openjdk-17-jdk
- update-alternatives --set java /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/java
- update-alternatives --set javac /usr/lib/jvm/java-17-openjdk-amd64/bin/javac
- apt-get install wget -y
- apt-get install -y openjdk-17-jdk
- mvn -version
- git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git
- cd spring-petclinic
- ./mvnw package
-  java -jar target/*.jar &
#- mvn package
#- java -jar -e -X -spring-javaformat:apply target1/spring-petclinic-2.1.0.jar &

artifacts:
paths:
- target/*.jar

docker-package:

image: docker:20.10.16
stage: package
services:
- docker:20.10.16-dind
script:
- docker login -u $CI_REGISTRY_USER -p $CI_REGISTRY_PASSWORD $CI_REGISTRY
- docker build -t $CI_REGISTRY/group/project/image:latest .
- docker push $CI_REGISTRY/group/project/image:latest

and I prepared another File for Dockerfile and used the usual command for build the image as per the CI/CD files above,

**##Start of the code###**

FROM maven:latest

WORKDIR /src

COPY .mvn/ .mvn
COPY mvnw pom.xml ./

git clone https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-petclinic.git
cd spring-petclinic

COPY src ./src

RUN ./mvnw package
RUN java -jar target/*.jar

ENV PORT 5000
EXPOSE $PORT
CMD [ "sh", "-c", "mvn -Dserver.port=${PORT} spring-boot:run" ]

any clue how can I fix it?

I tried to edit the file I mean the Pipeline file but it was working just fine, the problem I believe is on my Docker file, I used this repo for my project...

https://spring-petclinic.github.io/